# Move Listview Up when show Snackbar

Tags: android, android-listview, android-support-library, android-coordinatorlayout, android-snackbar

I need to move the listview up when I show a Snackbar in the bottom of the screen.

The snackbar works perfectly, but hide the content of the bottom of the listview.

This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblInformacion"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/md_green_500"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/clClientes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvClientes"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblEmpty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="No Result"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: yes, i use the CoordinatorLayout in the Snackbar.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ListSnackbarBehavior extends AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior {

            @Override
            public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent,
                                           View child, View dependency) {
                return super.layoutDependsOn(parent, child, dependency) && dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child,
                                                  View dependency) {
                if (dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) {
                    updateListTranslationForSnackbar(parent, child, dependency);
                }
                return false;
            }

            private void updateListTranslationForSnackbar(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
                int translationY = (int) getListTranslationYForSnackbar(parent, child);
                if (translationY > -1) {
                    ViewCompat.animate(child).translationY(-translationY).setDuration(100)
                            .setInterpolator(new LinearOutSlowInInterpolator()).start();
                }
            }

            private float getListTranslationYForSnackbar(CoordinatorLayout parent,
                                                         View listView) {

                View lastVisibleView = listView instanceof RecyclerView ?
                        getLastViewFromRecyclerView(listView) : listView instanceof ListView ? getLastViewFromListView(listView) : null;
                float minOffset = 0;
                if (lastVisibleView != null) {
                    final List<View> dependencies = parent.getDependencies(lastVisibleView);
                    for (int i = 0, z = dependencies.size(); i < z; i++) {
                        final View view = dependencies.get(i);
                        if (view instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout && parent.doViewsOverlap(lastVisibleView, view)) {
                            minOffset = Math.min(minOffset,
                                    ViewCompat.getTranslationY(view) - view.getHeight());
                        }
                    }
                }
                return -1;
            }

            private View getLastViewFromListView(View view) {
                ListView listView = (ListView) view;
                if (listView.getAdapter() != null && listView.getAdapter().getCount() > 0) {
                    int lastVisiblePosition = listView.getLastVisiblePosition();
                    if (lastVisiblePosition == listView.getAdapter().getCount() - 1) {
                        listView.smoothScrollToPosition(lastVisiblePosition);
                        return listView.getChildAt(listView.getChildCount() - 1);
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

            private View getLastViewFromRecyclerView(View listView) {
                RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) listView;
                if (recyclerView.getAdapter() != null && recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() > 0) {
                    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
                    int lastPartiallyVisiblePosition = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                    if (lastPartiallyVisiblePosition == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1) {
                        linearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(lastPartiallyVisiblePosition);
                        return linearLayoutManager.getChildAt(lastPartiallyVisiblePosition);
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I'm not sure if I got the translation y correct, but here is the deal:

1. You react only when there are changes on `SnackbarLayout`
2. Find if we are near the last item in the list
3. If the view overlaps, scroll to make it completely visible.
4. Lift the list to minus the offset when the `Snackbar` shows up and `0` when hides.

Comment: How I wish this would work... With listview I got a classCastException on  parent.getDependencies(lastVisibleView); With recyclerview I got no behaviours at all. Maybe I'm using this code wrong, was setting app:layout_behavior of listView to this class.